# How to specify a route member inside a block in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The following code:

```
map.resources :users, :has_many => :items
```

Could be written like this in a block:

```
map.resources :users do |user|
   user.resources :items
end
```

How could I write the following code in a block?

```
map.resources :users, :member => { :start => :post }
```

Also, where could I find documentation on writing routes in blocks?
The [Routes Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html) does not seem to show it.

Thank you!

Comment: The purpose of the block syntax is for nested routes. Why do you want to use a block to define custom REST actions on one resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 2.x doesn't allow you to use blocks for member definition.
With Rails 3.x you can write

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :start  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so in Rails 2 (2.3.5 is the version I tested it on):

```
map.resources :users, :member => { :start => :post } do |user|   
   user.resources :items   
end
```

From here: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/